# Acquiring the number of contracts for persons

Tags: performance, sql, sql-server

This script shows the number of contracts for persons. Table `Contract` has more than 82008 records and `Candidate` has about 7978.

Could you please suggest improvements for this script?

```
select ISNULL(CON.ContractCount, 0)
,      CAN.PersoonName
,      ... /* some fields from table Candidate (more than 25) */
from   Candidate CAN
       left join (select PersoonID, COUNT(*) ContractCount 
                  from Contract
                  group by PersoonID) CON on CAN.PersoonID = CON .PersoonID
where CAN.Type = 11
```

Comment: Hi, can you clarify what's in the "..." ? If it's not too long, please include it anyway.

Comment: "..." - there have to be more than 25 fields to select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, when doing left-join aggregation with a simple function (`count()`), it is easier to move the aggregation to be part of the select clause instead of as a subquery on the from clause.

As long as you are only pulling one aggregate from the sub table, it's easy.

Also, I presume there is at least one index on `Contract` where the `PersoonID` is the first (or only) column.

```
select (select count (*)
        from Contract
        where PersoonID = CAN.PersoonID
       ) as ContractCount
,      CAN.PersoonName
,      ... /* some fields from table Candidate (more than 25) */
from   Candidate CAN
where CAN.Type = 11
```